# How to Link File URLs?

Tags: files, apache-httpd, url, wordpress

I am currently running WordPress/Woocommerce on an Apache server.

I have files for sale on the server, located outside of the public path for security.

I am attempting to link the downloadable files using `file:///srv/protected/book1.pdf`, but the site is serving a unique URL path (as expected) but returning `this page is not available`.

Any ideas why these remote server files are not downloading?

The "protected" directory is owned by Apache and within the Apache group. The files within the "protected" directory are owned by their uploaders, but also within the Apache group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A url linking to `file:///` will try to access that file on the user's PC, not the server.

You must link to the file directly through the filesystem as your server allows, whether that be with a relative path `../../srv/protected/book1.pdf` or absolute `/srv/protected/book1.pdf`

Make sure your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in Apache is setup in a way that will allow these directories to be accessed (sym links or the data residing inside of the root).

Comment: The Symbolic Link worked to perfection. Thank you!

Comment: Quick follow-up... how would I prevent direct linking to the files via the symlink, as a paranoid protective measure?

Comment: Set the permissions to restrict only owners and groups to have access - `chmod 750 [filename]` should do nicely.

Comment: Hey @Deryck, I set permissions on the files to 640, but set able to access the files directly.

Comment: sounds great glad it worked out.  I use 750 just for my own kicks to live on the edge.  640 is the right way to go lol

Comment: Lol, was actually meaning it didn't work. Maybe what I'm asking for isn't possible, but I'm looking to have WooCommerce be able to deliver the files via unique URL download, but still have the public incapable of downloading the file if somehow they discover the direct link. Currently I am still able to download directly via "http://mydomain/protected/book1.pdf" even with 640 permissions, when I only want "http://mydomain/blahblah/?uniqueaddress" to work.

If that's not possible, its cool.

Comment: Oh did you set your Apache .htaccess (or better yet, the Apache site config file with `<Directory>`) to `Allow 127.0.0.1` or `Allow 192.168.0.0/16` and `Deny all`?  If not this other question is a promising roundabout method http://serverfault.com/questions/453811/how-to-configure-php-cli-on-linux-ubuntu-to-run-as-www-data